# How to add value to pointer to array

Tags: c++

I have 2 arrays of char in int, to count symbols in text. I definitely have to use char and int, no map.

```
int* counterCPU = new int[256]{ 0 };
char *cstrCPU = new char[book.length() + 1];
strcpy(cstrCPU, book.c_str());

CountCPURealisation(cstrCPU, counterCPU);
```

```
void CountCPURealisation(char* book, int* counter) 
{
    int lenght = strlen(book);
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        counter[book[i]]++;
    }
}
```

but when I try to run the code, i got an error:

> 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location

For this line: `counter[book[i]]++;`

I tried to use & instead of * but it didnt work. Hate c++, could you point me out to an error?

Comment: Make sure you're not going out of bounds of the array.

Comment: `char` is often signed, so you can go out of bounds. Casting to `unsigned char` would help.

Comment: *"Hate c++,... "* This is just the beginning.

Comment: Tactical note:  In `int* counterCPU = new int[256]{ 0 };` you know the size, so `int counterCPU[256]{ 0 };` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: [Yoda quote time.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFnFr-DOPf8)

Comment: *Hate c++* -- If you used `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, maybe you would like C++ a lot better.

Comment: Save yourself a bit of O(n) by passing the length of the string, `book.size()`, into `CountCPURealisation` getting the length of a `std::string` is about as close to zero cost as you can get without a compile-time constant. `strlen`... not so much.

Comment: _“Hate c++”_ — and yet there is no C++ in this question, one `std::string` abuse aside. Usually people hate C++ [because they have bad teachers](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk). Try to join a better teacher’s class if possible.